# How can I create Windows Container Docker image with Scoop preinstalled?

Tags: powershell, docker, dockerfile, windows-server-2016, scoop-installer

I have a Windows Server 2016 AWS Workspace. I was able to install Docker. I want to create an image that has Java 8 and the Scoop package manager. I get Java installed fine and the Scoop install runs during docker build but when I run the container, only Java is installed. scoop is an unknown command and I have to reinstall it. It's possibly installed under another user but I can't seem to find any trace of it. I would also love to `scoop install git curl` etc... a couple of utilities. I would like to run the image and the tools are all ready to go. Can anyone point me in the right direction? My Dockerfile looks like this so far

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2016

# $ProgressPreference: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2138#issuecomment-251261324
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

ENV JAVA_HOME C:\\openjdk-8
RUN $newPath = ('{0}\bin;{1}' -f $env:JAVA_HOME, $env:PATH); \
    Write-Host ('Updating PATH: {0}' -f $newPath); \
# Nano Server does not have "[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable()"
    setx /M PATH $newPath

# https://adoptopenjdk.net/upstream.html
ENV JAVA_VERSION 8u222
ENV JAVA_BASE_URL https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk8-upstream-binaries/releases/download/jdk8u222-b10/OpenJDK8U-jdk_
ENV JAVA_URL_VERSION 8u222b10
# https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/issues/320#issuecomment-494050246

RUN $url = ('{0}x64_windows_{1}.zip' -f $env:JAVA_BASE_URL, $env:JAVA_URL_VERSION); \
    Write-Host ('Downloading {0} ...' -f $url); \
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12; \
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile 'openjdk.zip'; \
# TODO signature? checksum?
    \
    Write-Host 'Expanding ...'; \
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path C:\temp | Out-Null; \
    Expand-Archive openjdk.zip -DestinationPath C:\temp; \
    Move-Item -Path C:\temp\* -Destination $env:JAVA_HOME; \
    Remove-Item C:\temp; \
    \
    Write-Host 'Removing ...'; \
    Remove-Item openjdk.zip -Force; \
    \
    Write-Host 'Verifying install ...'; \
    Write-Host '  javac -version'; javac -version; \
    Write-Host '  java -version'; java -version; \
    \
    Write-Host 'Complete.'
```

I tried adding

```
iex (new-object net.webclient).downloadstring('https://get.scoop.sh')
```

But then the image won't build so I removed that line.

How can I install scoop (or maybe chocolatey) in this image and include a couple utilities so that when the container is run, those utils are ready to use?